# How do I display all images a user has liked on Instagram (via API)?

Tags: jquery, api, instagram

I'd really love to be able to view the images I've "liked" on Instagram via a web app. In the API there's an endpoint for /users/self/media/liked, but I'm not sure how to take advantage of this. I'm assuming it would require user authentication? I was trying to build it off of [Potomak's jQuery Instagram plugin](https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram), but it wasn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

i found this link but i dont know how to do it in javascript or php! see if it helps u http://symmetricinfinity.com/2013/04/06/download-your-likes-from-instagram.html
and 
[Instagram API Docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked)

i wonder if any one can translate this to php or javascript!

source code from above refrence:

```
require 'restclient'
require 'json'

media_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"

urls = []

while media_url != nil
  response = RestClient.get(media_url)
  json = JSON.parse(response)
  media_url = json["pagination"]["next_url"]
  json["data"].each do |item|
    urls << item["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"]
  end
  # don't slam instagram's api
  sleep 0.2
end

urls.each_with_index do |url, idx|
  image = RestClient.get(url)
  path = Dir.pwd + "/#{idx}.jpg"
  File.open(path, 'w') {|f| f.write(image) }
end
```